# Error while making request to the server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have been working on an app where I need to make some requests on the server to get some data.
This works fine most of the time but sometimes I get an error
`Socket timeout` or `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` when the app gets these errors it crashes.
One way I thought to remove these error is by the following code:

```
var i = 0
while(i == 0){
    try{
        viewmodel.getRequestFromServer()
        i = 1
    }catch(e: SocketTimeoutException){
        i = 0
    }
}
```

But I have to make a lot of requests and this will make the code very long. Can someone suggest me a better way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Hey, try to add a random timeout before the second call and to count the attempts. Also don't forget check the internet connection before make network calls.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * call in a background thread (better to use RxJava for it)
 * */
fun call() {
    var attempts = 0
    val maxAttempts = 3
    val random = Random(1_000)
    while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
        try {
            if (attempts > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextLong())
            }
            viewmodel.getRequestFromServer()
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            // do something with the error
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            // the thread was interrupted
            // should return or do something with it
            return
        } finally {
            attempts++
        }
    }
}
```